# Downloaded a character model that has a skeleton but need help so i can pose it

Tags: rigging

I recently downloaded a character model and was hoping to play around with it. I am new to Blender so I've watched some tutorials on how to pose characters with armatures. But the character model I downloaded has a premade skeleton and there are no grey bone things. So I am not sure how to pose this character using the premade skeleton.

Here is the download link for the character. http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/bastet-50797.html

Screenshot of the premade skeleton
[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the rig and the model were created by another 3D software and have been imported to Blender. I doubt that this rig works well in Blender, but to answer you question first.

- In *Object Mode* Select the model <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Select the rig <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> With automatic weights

The bones shape can be changed in the properties panel:

[image]

For your first steps I would recommend to find another model that meets the blender conventions. Or use the rigify addon to create your own rig.